# C# object type - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm writing a program that calls some erp class/functions (the erp is pretty much obsolete and doesn't have any support available).  I'm having trouble define an 'object', and would appreciate some help in this regards.  thanks in advance

I have a class `typeUDDBTble` (definition further below).

My coding is.

```
typeUDDBTbl UDDB = new typeUDDBTbl();
UDDB.name = "xxxx";
UDDB.Rec = new typeRec[1];
// Edited, incorrect code
// UDDB[0].Items = new typeFld[1];
UDDB.Rec[0].Items = new typeFld[1];
```

The Items is an object array.  I tried using `new Object[1]`, or other `type(typeFld)`, but all get the

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Any idea how i can solve this problem?

The definition:

```
public partial class typeUDDBTbl : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private typeRec[] recField;
    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Rec", Order = 0)]
    public typeRec[] Rec
    {
        get
        {
            return this.recField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.recField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Rec");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "token")]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class typeRec : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private object[] itemsField;

    private string dummyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Fld", typeof(typeFld), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("LangFld", typeof(typeLangFld), Order = 0)]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "token")]
    public string dummy
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dummyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dummyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("dummy");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class typeFld : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string nameField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "token")]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your typeUDDBTble does not contain an indexer, so you trying to access its object with square brackets is invalid.

I suppose you meant:

```
UDDB.Rec[0].Items = ...
```

Also, you will have to initialize the first cell in `Rec` unless you want another exception.

```
UDDB.Rec[0] = new typeRec();
UDDB.Rec[0].Items = new object[1]
```

Comment: thanks,i am missing the UDDB.Rec[0] = new typeRec();  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
UDDB[0].Items = new typeFld[1];
```

`UDDB` is of type `typeUDDBTbl`, which does not have an indexer method.

It also does not appear to have a property called `Items`.

Comment: oops, sorry, the coding should be UDDB.Rec[0].Items

Comment: @Glen In that case.. `Items` is `null` because you haven't initialized it.